# Commutator of gauge Poincaré group

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, poincare-symmetry

I'm reading along with Hehl, von der Heyde, and Kerlick's [General relativity with spin and torsion](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258098262_General_relativity_with_spin_and_torsion_Foundations_and_prospects) on gauging the Poincaré group to include spin into GR.

They introduce the covariant derivative
$$D_\gamma = e^i_{\;\gamma}D_i = e^i_{\;\gamma}\left(\partial_i + \Gamma_i^{\;\alpha\beta}f_{\beta\alpha}\right)$$
where $e^i_{\;\gamma}$ is a tetrad, with anholonomic indices Greek and coordinate indices Latin, $f_{\beta\alpha}$ is an element of a spin representation of the Lorentz group, and $\Gamma_i^{\;\alpha\beta}$ is the spin connection.

The authors present the commutation relations of the group given by $f_{\beta\alpha}$ and $D_\gamma$: I understand and can derive two of these,
$$[f_{\alpha\beta},f_{\gamma\delta}]=g_{\gamma[\alpha}f_{\beta]\delta} - g_{\delta[\alpha}f_{\beta]\gamma}$$
$$[D_\alpha,D_\beta]=e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}\left(F_{ij}^{\;\;\gamma\delta}f_{\delta\gamma}-F_{ij}^{\;\;\gamma}D_{\gamma}\right)$$
from the Poincaré group algebra, with $F_{ij}^{\;\;\gamma\delta}$ the Lorentz gauge field and $F_{ij}^{\;\;\gamma}$ the translational gauge field.

However, I cannot see a route to deriving the third commutation relation,
$$[f_{\alpha\beta},D_\gamma]=g_{\gamma[\alpha}D_{\beta]} \tag{*}\label{*} $$
their equation 4.27.

My logic so far goes that
$$\begin{align}
[f_{\alpha\beta},D_\gamma] &=e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}f_{ij}e^k_{\;\gamma}D_k - e^k_{\;\gamma}D_k e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}f_{ij} \\
&=e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}e^k_{\;\gamma}f_{ij}D_k - e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}e^k_{\;\gamma} D_k f_{ij} - e^k_{\;\gamma}\left(D_k e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}\right) f_{ij}\\
&=e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}e^k_{\;\gamma}\left[f_{ij},D_k\right]- e^k_{\;\gamma}\left(D_k e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}\right) f_{ij}\\
&=e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}e^k_{\;\gamma}\left[f_{ij},\partial_k\right]+e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}e^k_{\;\gamma}\Gamma_k^{\;lm}\left[f_{ij},f_{ml}\right]- e^k_{\;\gamma}\left(D_k e^i_{\;\alpha}e^j_{\;\beta}\right) f_{ij}
\end{align}$$
Now the first term looks fine and will appear in $\eqref{*}$.  However, the second and third terms look like they will leave spin connections like $\Gamma_\gamma^{\;\bullet\bullet}$, rather than $\Gamma_\alpha^{\;\bullet\bullet}$ or $\Gamma_\beta^{\;\bullet\bullet}$ as required for $\eqref{*}$ (and terms like $\partial_k e_i^{\;\bullet}$, which are also unhelpful).  Would anyone be able to point out where I've gone wrong here, or give some pointers for a route forward?

Comment: Isn't (*) just the statement that the covariant derivative transforms as a vector under the Local  Lorentz group (I'm assuming that $g_{\alpha\beta}$ is the Minkowski metric)?

Comment: Yes, $g_{\alpha\beta}$ is the Minkowski metric.  I guess I don't see why the covariant derivative must be a local vector from its structure (this is probably the insight I'm missing!)

Comment: Would you agree that the vielbein transforms as a four vector under local Lorentz transformations (LLT) and as a rank 1 tensor under general coordinate transformations (GCT)? If you agree then you should be able to convince yourself that $D_{\mu}= e_{\mu}{}^{i}D_{i}$ transforms as a four vector under LLT's (consider, e.g., it's action on a scalar field).